# Get current internal pointer for 1st dimension of a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the current internal pointer of the 1st dimension of a multidimensional array. Is this possible with built in PHP functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

To check the first dimension, use:

```
current($array);
```

To check the second dimension, use:

```
current(current($array));
```

Comment: ah ok thx, I didn't know you could use current this way on multidimensional arrays.  I'll give it a try!  Cheers.